# LogStash cannot connect Postgresql and ElasticSearch in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to run Elastic Stack on docker-compose and import data from postgresql, but LogStash cannot connect to postgresql and ElasticSearch.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.0
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
       - 5601:5601
  logstash:
    build: ./logstash
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
      - 9600:9600
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
      - db
```

Dockerfile for logstash:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.9.0

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
COPY pipeline /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
COPY postgresql-42.6.0.jar /usr/share/logstash/postgresql-42.6.0.jar
```

pipeline/jdbc.conf

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/postgresql-42.6.0.jar" 
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db" 
    jdbc_user => "postgres" 
    jdbc_password => "password" 
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "updated_at"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
    statement => "
      SELECT * FROM users 
      WHERE updated_at < NOW()
      AND updated_at > :sql_last_value
      ORDER BY updated_at
    "
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
    remove_field => ["id", "@version"]
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec =>  "rubydebug"}
}
```

After staring docker-compose, all services except LogStash works fine, but the connection to postgres and ElasticSearch is denied in `docker-compose logs logstash` :

```
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:16,906][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:16,918][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:17,022][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:17,315][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 75 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 132 keys and 464 values
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:18,576][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline `main` is configured with `pipeline.ecs_compatibility: v8` setting. All plugins in this pipeline will default to `ecs_compatibility => v8` unless explicitly configured otherwise.
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:18,598][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/jdbc.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0xfd6132e@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:134 run>"}
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:19,062][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.46}
es-postgres-logstash-1  | [2023-07-28T11:18:24,311][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main]
es-postgres-logstash-1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(org/postgresql/core/ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(org/postgresql/jdbc/PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(org/postgresql/Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(org/postgresql/Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(jdk/internal/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(jdk/internal/reflect/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:472) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:330) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.connect(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:237) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.new_connection(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:248) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.make_new(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:154) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.assign_connection(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:209) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.acquire(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:139) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.hold(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:91) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.synchronize(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:293) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.test_connection(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:302) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.initialize(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/database/misc.rb:188) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyClass.new(org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(org/jruby/RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.connect(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:57) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.connect(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.69.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:124) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.jdbc_connect(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.4.4/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:123) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1507) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.jdbc_connect(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.4.4/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:120) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.open_jdbc_connection(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.4.4/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:163) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.register(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.4.4/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:309) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.register(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-mixin-ecs_compatibility_support-1.3.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/ecs_compatibility_support/target_check.rb:48) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.register_plugins(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:237) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1865) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(org/jruby/RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.register_plugins(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:236) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.start_inputs(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:395) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:320) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.run(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:194) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at RUBY.start(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:146) ~[?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:309) ~[jruby.jar:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:833) [?:?]
es-postgres-logstash-1  | Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

As for postgresql, I created ubuntu container in this docker compose network, installed psql and tried `psql -h db -p 5432 -U postgres -d db` and successfully logged in, so I think url and credential in `jdbc.conf` is correct.
Do you know any other possible cause?

Comment: I think you replaced exact thing we need to see with the ellipsis.

Comment: you say your successful test connected to host "postgres", while your URI is connecting to host "db".  If one worked, I would expect the other not to.

Comment: Replaced elipsis with exact logs. As for connection test, I had changed postgres service name to `db` . Just tested again and it works, so updated the command too.